# how customize the dataTableOutput in shiny app

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I want to see only three records in each page of my dataTableOutput. I have set page length to (`pageLength = 3`) but it does not show 3 rows in my table. 
The code is as following:

> server.r :

```
# display table
  output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
    (options = list(pageLength = 3))
    #update after submit is clicked
    input$submit
    #update after delete is clicked
    input$delete
    ReadData()
  }
```

> ui.r :

```
 box(
      title = "KPIs", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
      collapsible = TRUE,
     DT::dataTableOutput("responses"), tags$hr()

    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
    #update after submit is clicked
    input$submit
    #update after delete is clicked
    input$delete
    DT::datatable(ReadData(), options = list(pageLength=3))})
```

Comment: It works well. thank you so much. I do not understand why they gave you minus mark and gave me -3?

Comment: Can you please explain why the code that I write is not working?

Comment: i think you need to use `datatable(` into `renderDataTable(` , but its only my opinion